# jsonファイルの差分がある場合、jsonデータを更新したい。

Tags: monaca, json

アプリ内で、jsonファイルを読み込んだ箇所があるのですが、サーバー上のjsonファイルを更新してもアプリの内容に反映されません。(アプリを一端落とすと反映されたりもする。)反映されるようにするにはどのような処理を入れれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

取得しなおしても反映されないということであれば、通信内容がキャッシュされてないかを確認するのが良いのではないでしょうか。たぶんJSON かどうかは関係ないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> (アプリを一端落とすと反映されたりもする。)

とあるので、ダウンロードしたjsonファイルを保存するタイミングとそれを読み出すタイミング？
が逆転するなどして古いjsonファイルのデータを保持し続けてしまっていたりしませんか？

何にせよ、もう少し詳細にどういった仕組みで実装しているのかや、
具体的に関連部分のコードを明示された方が解決に近づく意見がもらえると思います。

Answer (score 1):

キャッシュが保存されているだけなら、ランダムなパラメータを付けてアクセスすればキャッシュを使わないように出来ます。